# Programmatically Noticing Frequent Subsequences in Python

Tags: comparison, data-mining

I have an open ended question. I have 22 ordered lists of symbols, and I want to explore ways to see if there are noticeable subsequences in the order or sequence of these symbols.

Background:
The symbols represent different types of actions that people undertake while trying to debug a system, and therefore, it would seem logical that they follow some predictable trend. For example, I expect that people would need to figure out what the problem is before trying to fix it, edit the code before testing it, etc. One important thing is that there might be several of the same symbol repeated, before moving on to a different symbol. For example, users may edit many different files before trying to run the code.

There are about 20 unique symbols, each ordered list of symbols is about 120 symbols long (length varies!), and there are 22 such lists.

I want to programmatically notice trends in these lists. How would I go about doing this?

Interesting subsequences could be any of the following:

- Symbol x is almost usually followed by symbol y
- Symbol u usually occurs in the beginning of the list, and rarely in the end
- Symbols usually occur in the following order: [1,3,7,1,2]

And the big one:

- Across all sequences, this is the overall subsequence [9, 12, 4, 2, 6]

What data mining techniques can I explore to help answer these kinds of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good question! I have several ideas to address this problem. Let me shortly describe one by one and hope that at least one of them will serve your purpose.

**[Frequent Pattern Mining](http://data-mining.philippe-fournier-viger.com/introduction-frequent-pattern-mining/)**

The most popular algorithm for pattern mining is without a doubt, [Apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm). It is designed to be applied on a transaction database to discover patterns in transactions made by customers in stores. But it can also be applied in several other applications. A transaction is defined a set of distinct items (symbols). Apriori takes as input (1) a *minsup* threshold set by the user and (2) a transaction database containing a set of transactions. Apriori outputs all frequent itemsets, i.e. groups of items shared by no less than *minsup* transactions in the input database. I believe frequent pattern mining approaches best matches your need.

**[Sequential Pattern Mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_pattern_mining)**

Sequential pattern mining is concerned with finding statistically relevant patterns between data examples where the values are delivered as a sequence. One example sequential pattern mining technique is [GSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSP_algorithm) (Generalized Sequential Pattern) algorithm.

**Clustering-based Approaches**

Clustering is the grouping of data into subsets or clusters, where the items (data) in each cluster share common traits. So, clustering-based approaches can be another interesting set to look at. Density based clustering or hierarchical clustering can lead to very interesting patterns.

**Graph-based Approaches**

I believe graph-based approaches can be effective as well. For example, if you create 22 graphs (each representing one ordered list of symbols), then you can look for a common subgraph that will give you the trending events.

**Predictive Models**

In state-of-art techniques of trend analysis, people has used predictive models like neural networks, kernel machines, decisiont trees (other rule based learning paradigm) and in many events they found them effective!

If i am given this problem, i would start with pattern mining techniques!